# Investigate the properties of complex function $f(z)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}$ where $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Investigate the properties of the complex function $f(z)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}$ where $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$

I am required to prove that it is bijective, continuous and find the inverse of this function. I face the problem due to the existence of $|z|^2$ in the function. Change it to $z\bar{z}$ seems like does not help much.

Comment: Well $|z|^2$ is non negative for all $z$, and so the denominator is positive everywhere. Thus $f$ is defined everywhere. Maybe it would be of some use to consider the exponential form of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\arg(f(z)) = \arg(z)$ you can work with absolute value version of your function
$$g: r \rightarrow \frac{r}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}$$ 
which can be inverted using a quadratic equation
$$g^{-1}:r \rightarrow \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$
Now you can check that 
$$f^{-1}(z) = \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}}$$
is indeed the inverse function defined for $z$ from the open unit disc  (note that all square-roots are the principal roots with positive real arguments)
$$f^{-1}(f(z))= 
\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1-\left| \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z^2|}} \right|^2}} 
$$
$$=\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1- \frac{|z|^2}{|1+|z^2||} }}$$
$$=\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{\frac{1+|z|^2-|z|^2}{1+|z^2|} }} = z$$

Comment: You could note that the argument of $f(z)$ is the same as the argument of $z$, which explains your guess for $f^{-1}$.